Write Serializable in Databricks
Databricks descirbes Write Serializable here:

For example, consider txn1, a long running delete and txn2, which
inserts data deleted by txn1. txn2 and txn1 complete and they are
recorded in that order in the history. According to the history, the
data inserted in txn2 should not exist in the table. For Serializable
level, a reader would never see data inserted by txn2. However, for
the WriteSerializable level, a reader could at some point see the data
inserted by txn2.

In both isolation levels, Serializable and WriteSerializable writes are serialized which means not executed in parallel. So the schedule/plan looks like the following (assuming that txn1 and txn2 are Transactions):



txn1
txn2





add(A)


delete(A)




When does the reader see data inserted of txn2?
